# Missing packages.config file

Tags: .net-core, visual-studio-2017

I'm trying to do something with .NET core in VS2017 RC, but I noticed the packages.config is missing, because they default in defining dependency in the project file.
However my configuration look like this:
[image]
so apparently it should use the file. Apparently it does not honour that configuration.
Furthermore,
Is there some reason we should prefer the dependency in the project file anyway?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

In previous versions of .net the csproj contained an assembly reference to a DLL that was stored inside a package. However that was treated seperately, from the packages.config which declared the packages to restore into the packages directory.

In dotnet core, packages are declared inside of the csproj file, as "PackageReference" The overall idea of a packages.config does not exist in dotnet core, which is why visual studio is not trying to create one for you. If you were using the old project system, you will find a packages.config is created for you.

Comment: Is there a way to turn this off?  I hate monolithic csproj files that violate the SRP.

Answer (score 23):

That setting you set won't be honored by .NET Core projects.

.NET Core always uses the package reference. So say goodbye to `package.config`.